# React Bootstrap modal appearing under background

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

In my render function I have the following code for a modal

```
<div id="newListModal" className="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div className="modal-dialog">
        <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
                <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 className="modal-title">Create new list</h4>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
                <p>Select category</p>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

All of the containing tags are positioned in the default way.

However, when I click on the button which triggers the modal, the modal appears under the background.

Since I have no special positioning of tags, I am assuming that this is a React issue.

Any ideas about why this is happening?

Comment: either `z-index` issue or you have modal somewhere in the middle of page, put modal at the end of page near footer or preferable before closing body tag `</body>`

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap? There's [an issue on the GitHub project](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16148) for 3.3.4+ that looks related, and is closed as "won't fix" for v3. There's also [a PR](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/16432) that tries to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your background and modal both are located under `root div`. So you can overcome this problem by creating another div separately.

**index.html**

```
<html>
<body>
     <div id="root"></div>
        <div id="list-modal"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**ListModal.js (component)**

```
return ReactDOM.createPortal(<div id="newListModal" className="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div className="modal-dialog">
        <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
                <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 className="modal-title">Create new list</h4>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
                <p>Select category</p>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>,document.getElementById("list-modal"));
```